# htacccess redirect to separate folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a record shop online.

The following URL example shows the product info page without a problem:

http://www.example.org/tp/html/product/33/record1.html

Im using an `.htaccess` file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

My problem is that the sound files are in a different folder on the server to the `detail.php` file.

The mp3 sound files are not shown on the page as they are in a different folder.

How do i tell the `.htaccess` file to look in the `../../sf` folder to find the mp3 files?

thanks!

Comment: In `detail.php` - or whatever HTML template it pulls in to display the record - why not just reference the sound files relative to the document root? e.g. `<audio><source src="/sf/track001.mp3" /> ... </audio>`

Comment: ive tried it and it doesnt work. the .htaccess file is preventing me referencing the exact location of the mp3 when using audio controls. This seems strange because my images show up just fine and they are in a separate folder to the .php files.